# Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. though the request latency took 4991ms

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

here's my fulfillment code in the inline editor : 
NOTE: requests are reaching my api server with 200 OK code but says deadline exceeded in the dialogflow platform. I hope you find with me a solution the faster you can`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');`

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  let number = request.body.queryResult.parameters['number'];
  var url = 'https://7400546e4d1e.ngrok.io/api/reclamations'+'/'+ number ;
  getDescription(url).then(response => {  
      var bot_response = "description:"+response.data.description ;
        agent.add(bot_response);

  console.log(bot_response);
    response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': bot_response });
  }).catch (error => {
    console.log("Something is wrong  !! ");
    console.log(error);
    agent.add(bot_response);
});

function getDescription(url) {
    const axios = require('axios');
    return axios.get(url,{timeout:10000});
}


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the function getDescription as an async function (ie. `async function getDescription(url){...}`).

This is because when you call `getDescription(url).then(response => {...})`, the .then() implies that it is asynchronous, which it is.